# Javascript Array Function Doesn't Return Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, next.js, return-type

I'm trying to return an Array of strings from this function:

```js
let returnArr = [];
export async function snapshotToArray() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
        db.collection('userinfo').get().then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                let id = documentSnapshot.id;

               returnArr.push(id).toString();
            });
            console.log(returnArr);

            return returnArr;

        });

}
```

It should be noted that the console seems to print exactly what I need it to print / return.

The Array creation Function is being called from this Function:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = await snapshotToArray();
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

For whatever reason it doesn't seem to be returning what I am seeing in the console.

Here is the Error I'm receiving:

```js
Error: Invalid `paths` value returned from getStaticPaths in /user/[name].
`paths` must be an array of strings or objects of shape { params: [key: string]: string }
```

I've tried so many different ways of doing this but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Together with the answer, consider using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) rather than `forEach` as a small optimization. Eg. `let returnArr = querySnapshot.map(documentSnapshot => documentSnapshot.id.toString())`

Comment: That's excellent feedback thank you so much. New to JavaScript so nuances like this are very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the snapshotToArray function has no return value.

```
let returnArr = [];
export async function snapshotToArray() {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    const querySnapshot = await db.collection('userinfo').get()
    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
        let id = documentSnapshot.id;
       returnArr.push(id).toString();
    });
    console.log(returnArr);
    return returnArr;
}
```

The following async-await usage should help you.

Comment: Thanks so much! If you're willing would you mind expanding on my original function not returning anything? I'm new to JavaScript but from my previous experience it seemed like it should be.